# GWT: Create Canvas widget from CanvasElement

Tags: gwt, html5-canvas

I want to wrap a `CanvasElement` (`<canvas>` in HTML) in a `Canvas` widget.

Many widgets (e.g. Label) have a static method `SomeWidget.wrap(Element)` for wrapping an existing DOM element.
I imagine Canvas does not feature such a method because not all browser support  and therefore the user should be forced to go through `createIfSupported()`.

Unfortunately the constructor in Canvas is private (protected would work), which means that Canvas can not be subclassed. (There isn't any constructor available in the derived class.)

Code snippets of `createIfSupported` and the constructor in the Canvas class:

```
  public static Canvas createIfSupported() {
    // check if canvas is supported; if it is not supported: return null
    return new Canvas(element);
  }

  private Canvas(CanvasElement element) {
    setElement(element);
  }
```

I ended up copying the Canvas class and making the constructor public.

Is there a better way to do this?
If not, what is the reasoning behind it (besides that `<canvas>` might not be supported)?

I am using GWT version 2.4.0.rc1.

Thanks,
Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old, but there is a solution in newer versions of GWT:

```
Canvas.wrap(canvasElement);
```

See [javadocs](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/canvas/client/Canvas.html#wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.CanvasElement)).

I don't know in which version of GWT it was added, but It works on 2.7.0.